# VS Code - space before function parentheses, for/while/if statements

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Which setting should I have to automatically spaces indents in function expressions, after for/while/if etc in VS Code for javascript?

For example:

```
let func = function () {}
for (let key in object) {}
```

Can I do it without extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `"javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true` rule in your `settings.json` file.

> File (Code) > Preferences > Settings

Then adjust if you want to format your code on type, on save or manually.

Comment: If you want it automatically, use the `"editor.formatOnType": true`

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: How to do this for C language?